# How to access my created class type after storing it into a dictionary as an object type?

Tags: c#

Hi I have a dictionary `Dictionary<int, object>` which will be holding different types of my own classes as values, I used a JSON serializer to save the dictionary and deserialized it in another form, however I can't access the object properties when I initialize the object, when I use dynamic type as the dictionary value it just gives me an error saying that the program cant convert JSON object to my class type.

my class, I have  a couple of other classes to store into the dictionary too

```
public class question 
{
       string q; 
       string desc;
}
```

so I tried to do this

`object quest = dict.Value`
But I can't access the properties of the object, even though when I print it out in console with `quest.tostring()` it shows all the properties neatly.

when I used dynamic I can initialize it as my class type and compile it without error and able to type

`question quest = dict.Value`
`string description = quest.desc`

but now during runtime, it says that it cant convert JSON object to my class

Comment: Serialize a class structure directly instead of using a Dictionary of objects.

Comment: but the thing is there will be different types of classes inside one dictionary and i want to be able to access all of the dictionary values.

Comment: Try with a *master* class, usually referred to as the `RootOject` which holds references of all the other classes.  When you serialize/deserialize, you pass the `RootObject` to the serializer/deserializer. The deserializer will rebuild the class structure and you can then access its members as usual.

Comment: This approach probably indicates a design problem. How do you expect to know which kind of object you're dealing with?

Comment: Yes that will be a problem too, not sure what to do :( i just need to store different classes in a single dictionary

Comment: @guyguy 1) don’t use dynamic. 2) when you decided to use this dictionary, there was a problem you wanted to solve by using it. It was going to make some part of your life easier. Now of course you just have two problems, but think back: What was the first problem you had, originally? Maybe there’s a better way to solve it.

Comment: @guyguy What’s the common base class for the page classes?

Comment: @EdPlunket Well the dictionary is used to create a form for people to fill out, the key represents a page number and the value represents the page itself, thats why i have different classes for the dictionary value because a page in a form is not always the same layout. So different types of classes will also help me tell the program how to create the form's page during runtime, i thought a dictionary would be best as the key,value pair is good for page ordering.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I dont have a base class, they are all different classes of their own, will a base class solve the problem? ill try making it.

Comment: @guyguy Do you understand what a base class is? It provides methods and properties that all the subclasses share. The subclasses can add more methods and properties as needed. It won’t solve the whole problem, but it’s a piece of the picture. Do you understand virtual methods?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I dont think i know but i can always do some research to learn how to create a base class and how to use it

Comment: @guyguy Excellent [rubs hands together]. Figure out what all pages have in common; that goes in the base class. They all have a page number, for example. The base class type replaces Object in the dictionary. Then figure out the operations they all perform, but in different ways: Those are virtual methods or properties. If an operation is performed *on* them differently, put that in a virtual base class method as well with subclass overrides. Stuff to create the page at runtime, bae class gets a virtual Create() method, each subclass overrides it with his own creation code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you i think i have a better idea of what to do now, will use your comment as reference when i finish learning about base classes

Comment: @guyguy So you can tell any class to create its page in the same way via a reference to the base class, and it handles the details. You don’t need to care which subclass it is. It’s page 9, whatever it is. This approach, properly applied, can, I think, do most of what you need. But there’s often some stuff left over. Do your research and write some classes and we’ll see where we stand. It’s quite late where I am; let’s talk later.

Comment: @EdPlunkett can you add your comments as an answer so i can accept it? thanks for all your help

Comment: @guyguy Let’s get the code working first!